# Typescript inline type declaration for object-member

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

In the following block of code defined the type of the attribute pens with the `<>`-Notation:

```js
return {
    ...defaultValues, 
    pens: 
      <[{penStrokeColor: string, penStrokeWidth: number, penOpacity: number}]>
      [...Array(5).keys() ].map((_)=> { 
        return {
          penStrokeColor: defaultValues.currentItemStrokeColor,
          penStrokeWidth: defaultValues.currentItemStrokeWidth,
          penOpacity: defaultValues.currentItemOpacity
        }})
  }
```

The code above works but my linter is complaining that this type-hint should be declared differently:

```
Use 'as [{ penStrokeColor: string; penStrokeWidth: number; penOpacity: number }]' instead of '<[{ penStrokeColor: string; penStrokeWidth: number; penOpacity: number }]>'  @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
```

Can this be done inline as well and if so, how?

Comment: Why are you using a type-assertion in the first place, though? That's a code-smell. (Angle-bracket type-assertions are going out-of-fashion because they're incompatible with JSX/TSX, very easy to confuse with type-parameters, and I personally find them ugly, whereas `as` assertions are far better, imo.

Comment: Side note: `[...Array(5).keys() ].map` could be `Array(5).keys().map`

Comment: See [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from) for a more natural way to create an array from a callback

Comment: @JuanMendes I previously used Array.from but for some reason all five elements would refer to the same instance - Thus, by changing one object it would change all five - I really wanted to make sure this issue was fixed, so I used the spread syntax (which is probably not necessary xD) and map

Comment: @MartinDallinger Laughed at "I really wanted to make sure this issue was fixed, so I used the spread syntax"

Comment: Same in hindsight :) - Nonetheless just using Array.from() and then replacing the value turned out to just place references to the same object in the array - Maybe just mapping directly from Array.from() would be simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just as the error says - use `as` instead of angle bracket notation to assert the type.

```
return {
    ...defaultValues, 
    pens: 
      [...Array(5).keys() ].map((_)=> { 
        return {
          penStrokeColor: defaultValues.currentItemStrokeColor,
          penStrokeWidth: defaultValues.currentItemStrokeWidth,
          penOpacity: defaultValues.currentItemOpacity
        }}) as [{penStrokeColor: string, penStrokeWidth: number, penOpacity: number}]
  }
```

But I don't think that's what you want - do you really want to tell TS that the created array is a *tuple*, with only a single item? Since you're creating 5 elements, you probably want an array type instead.

There's also no need for type assertion at all if that's the case - TS can properly infer that the created array is of the desired type.

```
return {
    ...defaultValues, 
    pens: [...Array(5).keys() ].map((_)=> { 
        return {
          penStrokeColor: defaultValues.currentItemStrokeColor,
          penStrokeWidth: defaultValues.currentItemStrokeWidth,
          penOpacity: defaultValues.currentItemOpacity
        };
    })
};
```

which infers the correct type without any TypeScript syntax at all.

Comment: Turns out that my original definition was wrong - I wanted it to be an array but defined it as a Tuple! As you correctly pointed out this conversion should not have been necessary - thx